# Looping through user list to create AD users in ansible

Tags: json, linux, ansible, active-directory, devops

I have a user list in json that is looped through in ansible playbook. I want the playbook to iterate through the list and create users in active directory, but skip over the already existing users in AD. Currently, it will give me an error if the user already exists in the AD. How do I loop through it and ignore the users already in AD?

This is what I have so far:

```
- name: Create user in AD
      community.windows.win_domain_user:
        name: '{{ item.firstname }} {{ item.surname }}'
        firstname: '{{ item.firstname }}'
        surname: '{{ item.surname }}'
        upn: '{{ item.upn }}'
        password: '{{ pass }}'
        user_cannot_change_password: false
        state: present 
        path: OU=Normal,OU=Accounts,DC=prod,DC=osur,DC=org
        groups: 
          - dev_users
        attributes:
          displayName: '{{ item.display_name }}'
        domain_username: '{{ domain_user }}'
        domain_password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
        domain_server: '{{ domain }}'
      with_items: "{{ Users.users }}"
      register: create_user_output
      ignore_errors: yes
```

Comment: so [your searches](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bansible%5D+ignore+failures) did not turn up [`failed_when:`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html), eh?